# Using Time with Micropython Mac OSX Python2.7

Tags: macos, python-2.7, sensor-fusion

## Setup

I am using a sensor fusing python module base off of the Madwick Algorithm. The source code can be found here [https://github.com/micropython-IMU/micropython-fusion/blob/master/fusion.py.](https://github.com/micropython-IMU/micropython-fusion/blob/master/fusion.py)

## Problem

Is there any way I could implement the function below ***pyb.elapsed_micro()*** and **pyb.micros()** without using the import pyb library with python2.7?

```
    import pyb
   # Integrate to yield quaternion
    deltat = pyb.elapsed_micros(self.start_time) / 1000000
    self.start_time = pyb.micros()
    q1 += qDot1 * deltat
    q2 += qDot2 * deltat
    q3 += qDot3 * deltat
    q4 += qDot4 * deltat 
     # normalise quaternion
    norm = 1 / sqrt(q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3 + q4 * q4)   
    self.q = q1 * norm, q2 * norm, q3 * norm, q4 * norm
```

Answer (score 0):

pyb.micros() - sets starting in microseconds

pyb.elapsed_time(start_time) - determines the elapsed time between startime and the time it took to call this function

## Solution

```
import time
def micros():
    return time.time() * 1000000  ##turns seconds into microseconds

def elapsed_micros(start_time):
    return start_time - time.time()*1000000
```

For more support check github link to issue - https://github.com/micropython-IMU/micropython-fusion/issues/1